# What is the best way to make a scrolling gridview which virtualizes items in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I want to use a gridview which can show 500 items easily. Like 3 items per line and many rows.. I don't want gridview to have REAL 500 items. For example if the screen can show 15 items at a time, I want it to reuse these items and replace their contents with the items corresponds to current scroll position. (Like the TableView in iOS or Virtualizing panels like in Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8).

Think about this like a photo application which lists the photos in 3 columns and you can scroll even 1000 items or 5000 items (it just take users own time to scroll to that deep, I just want the view to be able to handle items independent of their count)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have great news for you! The Adapter pattern was built for just this purpose.

> **Adapter** - An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view. The Adapter
>   provides access to the data items. The Adapter is also responsible for
>   making a View for each item in the data set. [See here for more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html).

---

> **GridView** - [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) is a [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. The grid items are
>   automatically inserted to the layout using a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html). For an
>   introduction to how you can dynamically insert views using an adapter,
>   read [Building Layouts with an Adapter.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews)

Use the examples shown in these pages to learn how to use a GridView with an adapter, then modify the example code for the adapter to load your pictures from where ever you want instead of from `R.drawables`.

Pay special attention to the part in the ListAdapter `getView()` method, particularly the `View convertView` parameter that gets passed to `getView()`. That parameter will be a "Recycled" view  if possible. (one that has fully exited the screen. and thus is longer being used) So by re-using it instead of creating `new` views every time you make it possible to scroll through a list of thousands of items while still only using exactly how many View objects it takes to show one full screens worth.